# How to kill colord-sane process

Tags: suspend, kill

On my system, `colord-sane` reproducibly prevents the system from suspending to RAM.

This is what I can find in the syslog:

```
systemd-sleep[32375]: Suspending system...
kernel: [55908.804118] PM: suspend entry (deep)
kernel: [55908.804123] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
kernel: [55908.816176] Freezing user space processes ...
kernel: [55928.828200] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.012 seconds (2 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
kernel: [55928.828567] colord-sane     D    0 32106      1 0x00000004
kernel: [55928.828577] Call Trace:
```

I tried to `sudo kill -9 colord-sane`, but it does not work, the process just won't go away. `sudo service colord stop` does not help either, it just produces this in the syslog:

```
systemd[1]: colord.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
systemd[1]: colord.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
systemd[1]: colord.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
systemd[1]: colord.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
systemd[1]: colord.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: colord.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

But even when the service is in the 'failed', the `colord-sane` process still lingers.

How can I terminate `colord-sane` so my system can go to sleep again?

(This is with KDE neon 5.13, which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.)

Comment: Did you use `kill` or `killall`?

Comment: I used both `kill -9` and `killall`, each with sudo privileges.

Comment: Try pkill. Alternatively, ps aux |grep colord should give you the PID, and you should be able to kill -9 the PID

Comment: Your question contains `sudo kill -9 colord-sane`, which I believe is incorrect.  `kill` expects a PID.  `killall` expects a name.